# Having trouble getting plots to show when using python in R-Markdown

Tags: python, r, pandas, r-markdown

I am writing a paper for a class which requires me to use python, but I like the interface of R-Markdown and have a template which I would like to use. I am using the reticulate package in R. Essentially, I am having no problem knitting the document unless I want to include a pandas boxplot or other figure. My code is below:

```
# using python
import pandas as pd
import pybroom
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import sys
import scipy
import numpy
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import xlrd
hei = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/zanod/OneDrive - The Ohio State University/Courses/PA 4040/hei.xlsx")
hei.boxplot(column="Percent Found Working", by= "Degree Subject (General)", rot = 90)
```

When I try to knit this document, I get a pop-up saying "this application failed to start...". Any ideas as to why this is happening? It doesn't happen for other code- just the plots it seems.

[image: Error message]

Update:here is a screenshot of my rmd file:
[image]

Here is the code. I have no issue knitting until I reach the hei.boxplot() function:

```
hei.groupby("Degree Subject (General)")["Graduates"].sum()
```

```
hei.groupby("Degree Subject (General)")["Percent Found Working"].mean()
```

```
hei.boxplot(column="Percent Found Working", by= "Degree Subject (General)", rot = 90)
```

Each are separate chunks

Comment: I am using the reticulate package in R...

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Qt like the error suggests? Qt is a graphical application. What is your entire Rmarkdown file look like?

Comment: @DanielJachetta Thanks for your response. I am not really sure what Qt even is or how to go about reinstalling it.  I've added a screenshot of my markdown file into the original post.

Comment: Does your error still happen if you remove all your python code? Break your problem down into smaller chunks, if the error says that you need to reinstall Qt to fix it, and you don’t know how to uninstall and reinstall it or what it is, that’s not helping me help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I've added some code in the original post. I tried knitting the document with the first two chunks, no problem. The third chunk gave me that error message. I can look around to figure out how to reinstall Qt and see if that helps @DanielJachetta

Comment: Try redownloading RStusio and reinstalling it, maybe that will fix your QT error

Comment: @DanielJachetta I use Anaconda on my PC, probably should have mentioned that. I've seen things online suggesting to create an environment using os.environ but I'm still getting the same issue